# MySQL How to do Operations on Time like 30:47 (30 minutes and 47 seconds)

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, time, datetime-format

I'm using MySQL and I currently have a VARCHAR column which stores times (in minutes and seconds) like "30:47" and "00:25" (25 seconds).  How can I make it so that I can do operations like SUM() and AVG() on this column and get the result back.

So if I did AVG() on "00:35" and "00:45" I would get "00:40".  Would I have to convert them to a decimal format first, then do the operation and then convert it back?  Or is there a column type that would support these operations?

Comment: Very, very unpleasantly is how.  Just use a TIME column.

Comment: You really should store this column as a `TIME` type rather than `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I can't vote up x10000 for this one, but if I could have done it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html) column.  It will support most operations intuitively.

Comment: @Ray I probably should have mentioned in my answer that you'll need to be careful about return types though.  For example, an AVG call might return an integer instead of a TIME type.